# Get self instance from within model in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to write a model method to receive easily some data:

My code looks like this:

```
class Transfers(models.Model):

    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
    person = models.ForeignKey("Person")

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def get_transfers(self):
        Transfers.objects.filter(person=self) //THIS IS NOT WORKING
```

How can i reference the instance to filter the transactions?

Comment: What do you mean, that isn't working? Not working *how*? What errors do you see?

Comment: Anyway, since this is a foreign key relationship, Django Ashkey gives you an accessor: `transfers_set`.

Comment: @Jurudocs: Why downvoting ? Well, might have to do with both a lack of research effort (how to get related models from a ForeignKey is well documented in Django, how to reference the current instance within a method and how to return a value from a function are both well documented in Python), and a lack of effort in the question itself ("is not working" is possibly the least usefull explanation of a problem)). If you factor in how easy it is to debug Python code, you really deserve the downwotes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be working, except that you are not returning anything.

Just do

```
def get_transfers(self):
    return Transfers.objects.filter(person=self)
```

By not returning anything explicitly, `None` is being returned.

An alternate way of achieving the same is:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def get_transfers(self):
        return self.transfers_set.all()
```